# C# List<> Index was out of range

Tags: c#, wpf

```
List<String> list_sub = new List<String> ();
int i = 0;
using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUB FROM Reque WHERE FORMAT = '" + format + "' AND CLIENTE = '" + client + "' AND CRIT = 'Cal'", sqlConnection);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlReader.Read()) {
        list_sub[i] = sqlReader["SUB"].ToString();
        i = i + 1; //Count
    }
    sqlReader.Close();
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

This code throws the error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

I was doing it with an array:

```
string[] list_sub = new string[20];
```

and was working fine, but not with a list (I read lists are better at this tasks...)

I thought that Lists worked pretty much identical to arrays, what am I missing?

UPDATE:

After filling list_sub with SQL Data, I want to change the text of some textbox (thats why I needed the i, I need to know how many values were imported)

This is the code (fills txtbox with list_sub data):

```
int y = 0;
var textsarray = new TextBox[] {
    txt_sub1, txt_sub2, txt_sub3, txt_sub4, txt_sub5, txt_sub6, txt_sub7,
    txt_sub8, txt_sub9, txt_sub10, txt_sub11, txt_sub12, txt_sub13, txt_sub14, txt_sub15,
    txt_sub16, txt_sub17, txt_sub18, txt_sub19, txt_sub20
};
foreach(TextBox txt in textsarray) {
    txt.Text = list_sub[y];
    y = y + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
list_sub[i] = sqlReader["SUB"].ToString();
```

You are treating a `List<t>` like it's a pre-dimensioned array.  You only need to do this to add items to an array:

```
list_sub.Add(sqlReader["SUB"].ToString());
```

Also, it looks like you no longer even need your index variable `i` unless you've omitted some code.

Comment: It seems to work, but how do I access the values then? txt.Text = list_sub[0]; will no longer work.

Comment: Sure you can access the values just like that -- txt.Text = list_sub[0] because `List<t>` has a default indexer.  However, when you have a brand new list, you can't expect it to have x number of empty elements waiting to be filled (like a pre-dimensioned array).  It doesn't work like that.  You can access elements by index *after* they have been added.

Comment: I'll update with a little bit more code, because I am getting again "Index out or range" when trying to change a txt.Text with data from list_sub. Check it please.